# How to properly set the map extent in Cartopy? In both UTM 51N and Plate Carree, the output is still "zoomed in" to the wrong area

Tags: python, mapping, gis, bounding-box, cartopy

The goal is to plot each earthquake from a CSV onto Cartopy's stock map. So one earthquake is one photo. These photos will be made into a GIF.

**Code**

```
import os
os.chdir(r'path')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point

df = pd.read_csv('emscPhilippines2008to2020_5lines.csv')
crs = "epsg:32651" 
geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
#projutm = ccrs.UTM(51)
ph = gpd.read_file('Provinces.shp')
bounds = ph.total_bounds
for i in range(gdf.shape[0]):
    ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
    ax.stock_img()
    ax.set_extent(bounds, crs=proj)
    g = gdf.iloc[i].geometry
    date = gdf.iloc[i]['Date']
    time = gdf.iloc[i]['Time_UTC']
    info = (date + " " + time)
    plt.plot(g.x, g.y, marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)
    plt.suptitle('Earthquakes in the Philippines from 2008 to 2020')
    plt.title(info)e
    plt.show()
    #plt.savefig("earthquake{0}.png".format(i))
plt.show()
```

**Results**

[image]

But if I comment out (put # before) ax.set_extent line, the result is a global map.

[image]

Even if I use the bounding [boxes of PH from here](https://gist.github.com/graydon/11198540) which is  [117.17427453, 5.58100332277, 126.537423944, 18.5052273625], the focus is still wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. So the list given by shapefile.total_bounds is wrongly formatted to what ax.set_extent needs.

Read the [documentation](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/geoaxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.set_extent) and the format should be

> Set the extent (x0, x1, y0, y1) of the map in the given coordinate
>   system.

The result is zoomed in correctly but low resolution

[image]

Comment: The doc is slightly too synthetic. what do x0, x1 y0 y1 refer to?